Calculus of Variation with density functions
Suppose I want to maximize  the following the functional:
\begin{equation*}
J[f] = \int_{0}^{1} m(x)f(x) \,dx 
\end{equation*}
subject to the constraint that the density $f(x)$ integrates to $1$
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{0}^{1} f(x)  \,dx = 1,
\end{equation*}
and that the expectation is finite and positive
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{0}^{1} x f(x)  \,dx = \mu \in (0,\infty).
\end{equation*}
This is basically an isoperimetric problem in variational calculus, applied to the density function $f(x)$.
The Euler equation of the problem is:
\begin{equation*}
 m(x) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 x.
\end{equation*}
However, I am confused about the meaning of the above equation, which is saying that basically the function $m(x)$ needs to be a linear function of $x$ (?).
Does it mean that the problem does not have a solution unless $m(x)$ is a linear function ?
